# Retrieving data from database using multiple ids - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have list of clients in my database with with unique ids. I am trying to retrieve these customers using these unique ids like this .

I want to get each clients name and phone and so i can process a message to them respectively. But with my query, i am only getting only one client and not all of my clients.

PS: when i return $explode, i am able to get all the ids i have selected.

```
  public function getCustomers(Request $request)
     {
        $ids = $request->ids; 

        $explode = explode(",",$ids);

        if(request()->ajax())
        {


        $clients = Client::whereHas('product', function($find_clients)use($explode)
            {
                 $find_clients->where('id',$explode);

            })->get(); 

           $get_customer_name = [];
           $get_customer_phone = [];

            foreach($clients as $key => $client)
            {
                $get_customer_name[] = $client->name;
                $get_customer_phone [] = $client->phone;

                return ['success' => $explode];                                
            }            
           }
}
```

**SMS query**

```
$query = "?key=$api_keyto=$implode(',',$$get_customer_phone)&msg=Dear ".$implode(',',$$get_customer_name)."Thank you";
```

Comment: Are you targeting all clients from clients table, or clients with a specific product?

Comment: where are the unique client ids? looks like that query is attempting to filter clients by the existence of `product` relationship where product ids exist, not client ids

Comment: @robbyrr i am targeting clients who have the products with the unique id. These products have the unique ids and they belong to specific customers. So i am looking for those customers who have those unique ids (meaning customers with those products

Comment: @lagbox yes, the products have these unique ids. Some clients have these products and therefore have these products. So i am trying to find these clients based on the unique ids of the products.

Comment: And do you have a relationship set up?. Like product belongsTo..or share clients table and products table/migration

Comment: yes i do.. i have been using this relationship already. I don't know if the ajax is causing this

Answer (score 1):

To find clients with an array of ids, try using whereIn instead of where.

Like so:

```
$find_clients->whereIn('id',$explode);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using whereIn instead of where

```
$find_clients->whereIn('id', $explode);
```

Comment: `return ['success' => implode(',',$get_customer_name)];`     returns the name of just one customer although, i have selected lots of ids

Comment: Could it be that the ajax request doesn't allow the loop?

Comment: @XamarinDevil because you are doing the return in the loop

Comment: @lagbox, even when the return is outside the loop, it returns just one name

Comment: try dd($explode) and dd($clients)